# Pandas dataframe to_csv() converts string "1" to "1.0" by default

Tags: pandas

Pandas dataframe to_csv() performs unwanted format conversion by default.

I have an Excel sheet that contains columns with integer values that refer to option items in a web application. I go to considerable lengths to convert these integer values to strings before exporting them to CSV. However, when I do, the to_csv() still converts a "1" to "1.0" and "0" to "0.0". First question is, how do I prevent Pandas from doing that? And second question, why does to_excel() NOT show this behavior. If I export my dataframe to Excel the integer values are correctly preserved.

I'm using Pandas 0.23.4 in a virtual environment on Mac OSX Mojave.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `NaN`/missing values in those columns? If so then it's converting the dtype to float.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I'll check this. Thnx!

Comment: So you either drop these rows using `.dropna` or replace/fill `fillna(0)` or whatever

Comment: I can't drop 'em but fillna("") will hopefully work. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: df[column].fillna('') works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find that your types have changed to a float when originally you thought that it was integer or all strings, then it's most likely that you have missing values such as `NaN`, `None`.

So you can either drop those rows using [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna):

```
df[column] = df[column].dropna()
```

or replace/fill these values:

```
df[column] = df[column].fillna(some_val)
```

where `some_val` is `0`, or whatever value you want.

This will then ensure the dtype for that column is not mixed or upcasted to `float`.